# Transmission won’t connect properly

Tags: transmission

I installed Transmission using the Terminal (`sudo apt install transmission-cli`), but when I open it and try to connect it, I receive this message:

> Couldn't connect to server

I am also trying to open magnet links, but they won’t work either. 
Should I install any extra package? Any help will be very welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck with transmission-daemon and for magnet links you may use extensions like ".torrent to transmission"